# Function to find minimum number of survivors

Tags: algorithm

Given are different types of cells, which can swallow their direct neighbors:

- Type X can swallow Type Y
- Type Y can swallow Type Z
- Type Z does nothing

Count the minimum number of survivors.

- Cells are represented by a 1-dimensional array.
- A cell can swallow only specified types, according to the above rules
- If there are multiple ways, choose the most optimal, minimising the number of survivors

```
## Example:

    C=[X,Y,Z,X,Z,Z,Y] 

Answer is: 3.
 
* C0 swallows C1, [X,Z,X,Z,Z,Y]
* C5 swallows C4, then C3 [X,Z,X,Y]
* C2 swallows C3 [X,Z,X]
```

How can such a function be implemented?

Comment: Show us your code and someone will help you improve it.

Comment: What is "most optimal"? As few or as many survivors? Optimal for X or Y or Z?

Comment: Optimal means as few as possible in general, no condition for specific types.

Comment: Are you sure your example is optimal? C1 could swallow C2 first...

Comment: I also think the correct answer is 2.

Answer (score 1):

We can make the following observations:

- If the list has no Y, then nothing can be swallowed
- If the list has only Y, then nothing can be swallowed
- In all other cases there is a possibility to swallow something, as that means there is an Y that has a neighbor that is not Y. If that neighbor is an X, then this Y can be swallowed by that neighbor, or if that neighbor is Z, then this Y can swallow that neighbor.
- An X cannot be swallowed, so all X remain.

We should therefore prioritise moves where an Y swallows a Z. This will not take away any possibility for an X to swallow an Y, ... so we can postpone those without risking to take a less optimal path.

When no more such moves are possible, perform the only remaining type of move, where an X swallows an Y.

If also that move is no longer possible we have arrived at a minimum.

To make sure the algorithm is efficient, the input could be stored in a linked list. The first step (where Y swallows Z) can be performed in one sweep through the linked list. If the current node is an Y and the previous node is a Z, then remove Z from the list, and keep the same node as current for the next iteration. If the previous node is not a Z, but the next node is, then remove the next node and keep the same node as current for the next iteration. If neither is true, make the next node the current node and repeat.

This has linear time complexity.

The next phase (where X swallows Y) follows the same principle.

### Implementation

I will give here an implementation in Python. First follows the code for a generic doubly linked list, using a sentinel node:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, val, prev=None):
        self.val = val
        self.prev = prev or self
        self.next = prev.next if prev else self
        self.next.prev = self.prev.next = self

    def remove(self):
        self.prev.next = self.next
        self.next.prev = self.prev

class LinkedList(Node):
    def __init__(self, lst=None):
        super().__init__(None)  # A sentinel node
        if lst:
            node = self
            for val in lst:
                node = Node(val, node)

    def values(self):
        for node in self.nodes():
            yield node.val

    def nodes(self):
        node = self.next
        while node != self:
            yield node
            node = node.next
```

The actual algorithm would then look like this:

```py
def swallow(c):
    ll = LinkedList(c)  # create doubly linked list for input

    for eater, food in ("YZ", "XY"):  # two phases
        for node in ll.nodes():
            if node.val == eater:
                while node.prev.val == food:
                    node.prev.remove()
                while node.next.val == food:
                    node.next.remove()

    return list(ll.values())  # return result as a standard list
```

You could call it as follows:

```py
c = ["X","Y","Z","X","Z","Z","Y"]
print(swallow(c))  # ['X', 'X']
```

### Alternative implementation

Instead of a linked list, you could also use a string and a regular expression to remove:

- any sequence of Y that occurs right before a Z
- any sequence of Y that occurs right after a Z
- any sequence of X that occurs right before an Y
- any sequence of X that occurs right after an Y

... in that order.

```py
import re

def swallow(c):
    s = "".join(c)  # convert to string
    s = re.sub(r"Z+Y", "Y", s)    
    s = re.sub(r"YZ+", "Y", s)    
    s = re.sub(r"X+Y", "X", s)    
    s = re.sub(r"YX+", "X", s)    
    return list(s)  # convert back to list
```

Comment: `#(:X :Z :X)` is an example of a minimal position which cannot be reduced further. I see a discrepancy in your answer and the question, regarding the swallowing-rules.

Comment: @BitTickler, I agree  with the example. How does this conflict with my answer? It actually is an example of my first bullet point: *"If the list has no Y, then nothing can be swallowed"*.

Comment: Right - the last bullet item confused me at first glance. I interpreted it as if **only** X can remain.

Answer (score 1):

You can see it as a typical branch and bound problem, like tic tac toe or other similar games, where you maximize a target function while you recursively search for the "best" move in a given position (C).

The following code demonstrates the principle.

- `can-swallow-p` checks if a neighbor can be swallowed and returns `T` or `NIL`.
- `generate-moves` generates a list of possible moves from a `position`.
- `eval-position` generates an integer value which denotes how "good" a position is.
- `do-move` takes a position and a move and returns the resulting position.
- `maximize` is the search function which looks for the best resulting position and its value.

With those functions in place, which in one form or another occur in any similar problem (often games), you can build a solution, which is basically a depth first recursive search.

Many algorithms are publicly known, to optimize the efficiency of the brute force version I wrote in my demo code below.

```cl
(defun can-swallow-p (position eater eatee)
  (if (< -1 eatee (length position))
      (let ((eater-value (aref position eater))
        (eatee-value (aref position eatee)))
    (cond
      ((and (eql eater-value :x) (eql eatee-value :y)) t)
      ((and (eql eater-value :y) (eql eatee-value :z)) t)
      (t nil)))
      nil))

(defun generate-moves (position)
  (let ((result nil))
    (if (= 0 (length position))
    nil
    (loop
      for i below (length position) do
        (let ((left (- i 1))
          (right (+ i 1)))
          (when (can-swallow-p position i left)
        (push (cons i left) result))
          (when (can-swallow-p position i right)
        (push (cons i right) result)))))
    result))

(defun eval-position (position)
  "From the question it is not clear, what is optimal.
So for the purpose of demonstration we choose, that 
shorter positions are 'more optimal' than longer ones."
  (- (length position)))

(defun remove-at (sequence index)
  "Does not modify sequence. 
Returns a copy instead, with item at index removed."
  (concatenate 'vector
           (subseq sequence 0 index)
           (subseq sequence (+ index 1))))

(defun do-move (position move)
  "Returns a new position, which results from the move.
move is a dotted pair of eater index and eatee index.
"
  (let ((eatee-index (rest move)))
    (remove-at position eatee-index)))

(defun maximize (position depth best)
  (let ((moves (generate-moves position)))
    (if moves
    (let ((value
        (loop
          for m in moves
          for child-position = (do-move position m)
          maximizing (maximize child-position (+ depth 1) best))))
        value)
    (let ((value (eval-position position)))
      (when (>= value best)
        (format t "~D ~A~%" value position))
      value))))
  
  
(defun analyze (position)
  (maximize position 0 (eval-position position)))


(defun test()
  (analyze #(:X :Y :Z :X :Z :Z :Y)))
```