# Parse list and print all final paths

Tags: tree, traversal

Given lines with different indentation

```
orange
 blue
  yellow
  black
  white
 green
```

Print all final paths.

Expected output

```
orange/blue/yellow
orange/blue/black
orange/blue/white
orange/green
```

How to parse all lines(non binary tree) to print final(complete) paths?

Comment: What is your programming language? What is the trouble you bumped into when trying?

Comment: You never gave feedback on a previous question of yours [that I answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66323049/5459839). Hope you will not stay silent now...

Comment: any language, my current problem: I try to split this list into sublists in recursion, but I cant get full path

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The algorithm will use a stack:

Keep a stack of pairs, where each pair consists of a (partial) path and the indentation of its last part. Entries in the stack are always increasing by indentation. The stack starts empty.

For each line from the input, determine its indentation. As long as there are indents on the stack that are equal or greater, remove those pairs from the stack. Then get the path that's on top of the stack, append the current line to that path (without its indent, separated by `/`), pair it with the new indentation, and push that unto the stack. Output that path and repeat the process for the next input line.

Here is an implementation in JavaScript:

```js
function getIndent(s) {
    return s.search(/\S/); // Index of first non-white-space character
}

function getPaths(text) {
    let stack = [];
    let paths = [];
    for (let line of text.split("\n")) {
        let indent = getIndent(line);
        while (stack.length > 0 && indent <= stack.at(-1).indent) {
            stack.pop();
        }
        let path = (stack.length > 0 ? stack.at(-1).path + "/" : "") + line.trim();
        stack.push({path, indent});
        paths.push(path);
    }
    return paths;
}

// Sample input
let text = 
`orange
 blue
  yellow
  black
  white
 green`;
 
for (let path of getPaths(text)) {
    console.log(path);
}
```

Comment: thanks @trincot, this solution prints all paths, so I add path only if  next line has less ident or current line is last one.